# How I can remove all alphabates from a string but not the minus (-) sign?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to insert some numbers in my database from a line

```
CreateObject(19456, 1957.27698, 916.52063, 11.22560,   0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
```

So i want to remove all alphabates also `;` , not the commas or fullstops also not the minus signs

I have tried with a preg_match

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $line);
```

it removes alphabates and `;` but also it removes minus sign

```
$name = $_POST['mapname'];
$text = trim($_POST['maps']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind
foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    $string = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $line);
    $pos = explode(",", $string);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO maps (model,x, y, z,rx,ry,rz,name)
    VALUES ('".$pos[0]."','".$pos[1]."', '".$pos[2]."', '".$pos[3]."','".$pos[4]."','".$pos[5]."','".$pos[6]."','".$name."')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
if ($result === TRUE) {

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Add `-`, `"/[^0-9,.-]/"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `/([^-0-9,.]+)/g` as a regular expression.
You must also escape the minus sign, but it is a special character so you escape it at the beginning itself and then escape the other characters. Next, you must sepcify quantity of the match characters with `+` (one or more). `g` after the expression stands for "global" - return all matches, not only the first one.

[This website](https://regex101.com/) is very handy when testing regex expressions.